# Improving JNA Performence

Tags: java, c, jna

I have the following situtuation on the C side I have a function that builds and returns an array of integers representing RGB values for an image,

```
  int* pxs(Image* m){
    int* colors = malloc(height * width * sizeof(int));

    //fill the array

    return colors;
   }
```

On the Java side I retrieve it using,

```
     //invoke
     Pointer ptr = ref.getPointer();
     int pxs[] = pointer.getIntArray(0, width*height);

     //to an image
     Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(new MemoryImageSource(width, height, pxs, 0 ,width));
```

Then the image gets painted on a panel, from my timing doing all that takes around 50 60 ms, images are from a camera so I get a new one and paint in a loop but after a while (10 secs or so) my machine comes to an halt. I am thinking this is due to garbage collection? so I was wondering if there is a way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are never `free`ing the colors array! Unless JNA does majic, Classic memory leak.

It may be a better idea to pass a ByteBuffer to the native function and have `pxs` take a `char *` to be filled with data.

Comment: I was under the impression that freeing that pointer was jna's job thats why I never free ed it.

Comment: There may be some sort of ownership transfer function or an array creation function that allows Java to own the pointer ( like JNI's NewObjectArray) but when you use `new` or `malloc`-family functions, you must manually manage the memory.

Answer (score 3):

Besides the missing free, you must take additional care as this may lead to memory problems anyway:

If you repeatedly allocate memory from "c space" (not the heap), the VM does not feel like collecting garbage because heap space is not used up. But DirectByteBuffers will free allocated c space only within the finalize method -> This leads to a "virtual" memory leak.

You can "workaround" this using frequent calls to "System.gc" or even better not allocate so much c memory, for example by only using a single transfer buffer.

Answer (score 3):

As well as the memory leak that [mtraut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674320/improving-jna-performence/4674593#4674593) and [Hamza Yerlikaya](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674320/improving-jna-performence/4674393#4674393) pointed out, you are also making an unnecessary copy of the pixel data (the `MemoryImageSource` wraps the array, but then the `Image` allocates its own buffer and copies the source pixels into it.)

You can avoid this by creating a `BufferedImage` that shares the array:

```
ColorModel cm = ColorModel.getRGBdefault();
DataBuffer buffer = new DataBufferInt(pxs, width * height);
WritableRaster raster =
    Raster.createPackedRaster(buffer, width, height, width,
                              new int[] {0xFF0000, 0xFF00, 0xFF, 0xFF000000},
                              null);
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(cm, raster, false, null);
```

Comment: above code throws an exception telling raster and color model is incompatible.

Comment: @Hamza Yerlikaya, You're right, there was an argument missing.  Fixed.